# How to pass Function as parameter to computeIfAbsent method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, hashmap

I am new to Java, kinda transition from C# to Java.
`java.util.function` has a interface defined as `Function` which is input to `computeIfAbsent` method of `Map`.

I wanted to define and delegate that function to `computeIfAbsent` method.

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k => new SomeObject())
```

works but *I wanted it with callback where func.* But the problem is `Function` requires input parameter to be defined. How can I set it to `void` or with no argument.

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, func);
```

Comment: Why is “Function requires input parameter to be defined” a problem? Can you describe what you actually want to do?

Comment: my computeIfAbsent is inside a loop. say (25000) times the loop is executed.
if i follow traditional approach everytime the lambda function will be created and then passed to the computeIfAbsent function. Why it should always be created. Can't we just store it in function and pass it.

Comment: Yes you can. If that’s your question, why don’t you ask exactly that, instead of the not even remotely related “*How can i set it to void or with no argument*”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`computeIfAbsent` will always have an input parameter for the passed `Function` - that would be the key.

Therefore, just as you can write:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new SomeObject());
```

you can also write (assuming the key of your `Map` is a `String`):

```
Function<String,SomeObject> func = k -> new SomeObject();
map.computeIfAbsent(key, func);
```

Comment: I am using Map collection.
I modified your answer with Function<String, SomeObject> func = k -> new SomeObject(); as my keytype was string

Comment: your previous answer was generic. please keep that only. please make it generic and add explanation with an example. That will solve the purpose and will also be useful for others.
Function<MapKeyDataType, FunctionReturnDataType>

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a lambda that takes the parameter and calls your function, ignoring the parameter.

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> func());
```

Answer (score 2):

If `func` is not computationally expensive and has no side-effects then you can just use `putIfAbsent` (notice it's '**put**', not 'compute') and call the method directly. It is semantically equivalent.

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, func());
```

`func` will be evaluated every time, regardless of whether it's going to be inserted, but provided it's quick then that's not really a problem.

Comment: That will only compile if `func()` returns a `Function<K, V>`.

Comment: Sorry, got stuck at `compute` and missed the `put`.

Answer (score 0):

The `computeIfAbsent(Key, Function)` used to compute value for a given key using the given mapping function, if key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null) and enter that computed value in `Hashmap` else null. as per syntax

```
public V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K, ? extends V> remappingFunction)
```

you can write -

`map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> Object());` or

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> fun());
```

Answer (score 0):

`computeIfAbsent` takes two parameters:

- `key` - key with which the specified value is to be associated
- `mappingFunction` - the function to compute a value (this of type
  [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), a Functional Interface, which takes one argument and
  returns a result).

There is no other way to specify the parameters to the method `computeIfAbsent`. Here is an example using this `Map` method:

Input: `Map<String, Integer> map: {four=4, one=1, two=2, three=3, five=5}`

```
map.computeIfAbsent("ten", k -> new Integer(10));   // adds the new record to the map
map.computeIfAbsent("twelve", k -> null);           // record is not added, the function returns a null
map.computeIfAbsent("one", k -> new Integer(999999));   // record is not updated, the key "one" already exists -
                                                        // and has a non-null value
map.put("eleven", null);                                // new record with null value
map.computeIfAbsent("eleven", k -> new Integer(11));    // updates the record with new value
```

The output: `{four=4, one=1, eleven=11, ten=10, two=2, three=3, five=5}`

**Consider the code**: `map.computeIfAbsent("ten", k -> new Integer(10));`

The code says I want to insert a new mapping (key-value pair) to the `map`. The method `computeIfAbsent` needs to specify the *key*, which is "ten". The *value* is derived from the `Function` which takes the key as input parameter and produces a result; the result is set as value to the mapping.

In the example, the key-value pair are added to the map: "ten", 10.

The lambda expression `k -> new Integer(10)` is an instance of the *functional interface* `Function<String, Integer>`. The code can also be represented as:

```
Function<String, Integer> fn = k -> new Integer(10);
map.computeIfAbsent("ten", fn);
```